# How to view MATLAB neural network as graph (vertices and edges)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure

I know this question may be a long shot, but is there a way to view a MATLAB neural network as a graph of vertices and edges rather than the default as below:

[image: matlab NN]

In other words is there a way to view it in this way within MATLAB?

[image: graph NN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the format of Neural Networks Toolbox, but I can help you with the drawing part.
There is a command called `gplot` that draws adjacency matrices (taken directly from Matlab help).
You can adjust it to show circles instead of points:

```
k = 1:30;
[B,XY] = bucky;
gplot(B(k,k),XY(k,:),'-')
axis square
hold on ;plot(XY(k,1),XY(k,2),'o','MarkerSize',30,'MarkerFaceColor',[1 1 1])
```

[image]

You would need to compute `XY` based on the depth of your layer (not too hard), and play around a little bit with nodes (circle) size and distance between nodes.

Comment: OK I'll try see what I can find out, and I'll re-edit this post if I hopefully make any progress, thank you!